# Galaxy S6 edge sms not working

Tags: sms, 7.0-nougat

My Samsung  Galaxy S6 Edge (7.0 Nougat), cannot send basic sms messages, I have to add a Subject to every text. this makes having a conversation with anyone impossible. How can I restore this messaging app. This may have began with the last update to (7.0 Nougat), it was sudden. Samsung has been no help and I cannot afford a new phone. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks, Rick.